# Missing std::string functionality

Tags: c++, string, std, qstring

Anyone knows why the C++ standard library’ `std::string` class (or more generally the `std::basic_string` class template) lacks ordinary character string functionality such as uppercasing, substring replacement and trimming, etc., compared to e.g., QString class from Qt, or Python strings?

Comment: Couple of items which may be worth perusing: 1) [`ctype::toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/toupper/) (particularly, the second overload which takes a range) and 2) an [email](http://cpptips.com/intl_string) by James Kanze on concerns with uppercasing strings.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take a stab at this...

The template `std::basic_string` was originally written and included in the [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html), which represents the "abstract" parts of the Standard Library as we know it (containers, iterators, algorithms, allocators, etc.). This also included `std::string`.

Notice how there is absolutely no encoding, internationalization or locale dependent functionality in the [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html). It wasn't a design goal.

Now my take on the happenings of previous generations: When C++ was standardized, there was need for a comprehensive Standard Library. The STL was a very good fit for this, and was taken over almost verbatim. Only later was stuff like `<iostream>` and `<locale>` added. The clunky and very incoherent interface differences between streams and strings only prove this "let's throw it all together" attitude.

As with many `std` facilities, interoperation between the components wasn't optimized. On top of that, the simplicity of a small C++ function wrapping existing C functionality (like `toupper`) have been used as a reason not to include this in the Standard Library.

By a next revision of the Standard (and thus the Library it comprises), backward compatibility prevented any useful and necessary changes (injecting locale into `std::string` functionality) from being added.

Note that this conjecture does not at all explain why for example a `std::trim` taking a string and locale object wasn't added. It does kind of attempt to explain the background process involved.

Now that all has been said, I wholly agree the C++ Standard Library is clunky and incomplete in its general usefulness.

**UPDATE**: I've been informed that my timeline is reversed: the Standard Library (and iostream) existed before the STL was added. The point above is still valid though: STL was copy-pasted, with little to no integration (simple example: the missing until recently `std::basic_istream<T>::open(const std::basic_string<T>&)`, which will be deprecated in the next iteration due to `std::filesystem` stuffs).

Answer (score 4):

Can't answer about all missing features in the most general sense, but…

The two features mentioned, trimming and uppercasing, are locale-dependent. They aren't only functions of characters, but also the encoding and language being used.

`std::string` doesn't really handle that. Although in practice, everyone uses Unicode with whitespace as defined by ASCII, that's not general enough for the kind of standardization process that defines C++.

Such operations are obtained by streams (for example, read out of a `std::stringstream` to strip excessive space) and locale objects (for example, accessed through `std::tolower`).

Comment: I think along the same lines but if you can have standard library functions for single characters, why not extend them over a collection? I'd just go along with the fact that a) the standard is not perfect yet and b) perhaps there may be difficulties in guaranteeing that an operation (such as `toupper`) on an entire collection is more difficult to define (because some characters may be pure ASCII and some Cyrillic in a single string -- I haven't thought through this bit completely yet) than it is for single characters (where you can put a check before conversion and act accordingly).

Comment: The last bit needs some clarity: Error handling over a string of characters with mixed `toupper` semantics is difficult. I'd say the same can be applied to trimming -- punctuation (do you consider an apostrophe in elision in French *l'arbre* part of the string?) is difficult to codify without going diving into an even deeper problem than what the scope of the language library standard may define.

Comment: @dirkgently It would be nice if there were a `std::string::toupper` function taking a `std::locale` with a default argument. There is a certain level of poor interface design, especially around `char_traits`. But as for features being *missing*, the library as a whole does plenty if you look outside `std::string` proper (and there's nothing wrong with that).

Comment: Actually, right now, I have two questions: a) How do you deal with special characters (viz. the apostrophe in *l'arbre*) and b) How do you handle errors that may occur for a part of the string when converting case/trimming whitespace (do you trim out `notdef` characters or put a default value)? Any ideas?

Comment: @dirkgently: re the "how to", as i see it it's a very separate question. do post it as an SO question! but it's relevant in an odd sort of way, because it illustrates the *current* impractical mindset that a standardized solution needs to be apparently perfect and complete, for any reasonable generalization of the original problem. clearly that criterion was not applied when adding `std::string` itself. and so, clearly, that criterion is not any explanation of how `std::string` can be missing e.g. trimming and splitting (not to mention simple uppercasing).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I did not get the part where you say *that criterion was not applied when adding `std::string` itself*. Can you elaborate? If I were to put myself in the shoes of a library implementer those are two questions (among many others perhaps) that would keep me from implementing those particular members. The point I'm trying to understand is this: Is a collection of characters more difficult to operate on than a single character? Also, from what I hear, the strings library was cobbled together from a number of competing and existing implementations.

Comment: ... I'm sure some of those libraries did/do have these operations. If the standard did not incorporate them I'd assume that the implementations must be wildly different in their characteristics (semantics/syntax/error handling).

Comment: @dirkgently: i say, let's wait until someone with D&E or some other authoritative source (they do exist) chimes in.

Comment: Its a bit short sighted to think everybody uses unicode and/or ascii. Its just not true. Japanese development have been using shift-jis for many years and have appropriate tools for this environments picking up and moving to unicode just because america does is not a small en-devour.

Answer (score 2):

Poor functionality? Is considered to be one of the bloated components in the *Standard Library*. You have an entire set of *algorithms* that operate on `std::string`s, all the standard algorithms. Don't restrict yourself to member functions, there is much more in an interface than that...

Comment: -1 fallacy. the bloat of irrelevant functionality is evidence of the poor functionality, not counter evidence. `std::string` (or more generally `std::basic_string`) has extremely poor functionality *as a string*. try simple things like uppercasing a string, or replacing all occurrences of a substring with another. even more basic, try trimming a string. the C++ `std::string` is good for one thing only, and that's as a *standard* way to pass strings around, even if it's needlessly inefficient and restricted for that purpose.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: The bloated functionality is not irrelevant, it is duplicated within the string itself or the standard library. Look for instance at `size` and `length` for a very simple example. This was the result of combining a standalone string library with the _STL_.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: If you get to know your _Standard Library_ well enough you will see that the functionality is there, only for every type of _Sequence_, not just `basic_string`. For instance, `for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), toupper)` uppercases the entire string.

Comment: since your code example has Undefined Behavior, it seems that your claim to know the standard library better than me, is incorrect.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: Its just _pseudocode_, but I would still like to know how is it _UB_?

Comment: `toupper` requires a non-negative argument or the value `EOF`. so it can work for pure ASCII, but not for any character encoding in actual use today. with e.g. Latin-1 and signed `char` type it has UB if passed a Norwegian `Æ`.

Comment: @K-ballo: What about trimming and splitting (with string, not character, as a separator)? Can it be done easily without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: For a supporting viewpoint see Herb Sutter's [GotW #84: Monoliths Unstrung](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm). He really rips into the `std::string` class.

Comment: @Cheers: "it can work for pure ASCII, but not for any character encoding in actual use today." `std::string` doesn't use *any* particular encoding. Once you step outside of ASCII, you're not asking for `std::string` anymore; you're asking for a `std::utf8_string`, which is a completely different issue.

Comment: @NicolBolas: sorry, I fail to understand your comment. and that doesn't mean that the comment is likely to be beyond my ken. on the contrary.

Comment: @Cheer: My point is that, if you're using an encoding that the standard doesn't understand, you can't expect the standard library functions like `toupper` to support it.